# Flash anim doesnt want to show IE

Tags: asp.net, flash, internet-explorer, animation

I have flash animation on my web site, in all other browsers except IE shows.Header is same size as object.

```
<div id="header">
            <object style="width: 760px; height: 128px; margin-top: 3px" codebase="http://test.eu-seed.net/safenet/pict/banner3.1.swf">
                <param name="movie" value="http://test.eu-seed.net/safenet/pict/banner3.1.swf" />
                <embed src="http://test.eu-seed.net/safenet/pict/banner3.1.swf" quality="high" width="760"
                    height="128" name="myMovieName" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginpage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
        </embed>
            </object>
        </div>
```

What could be the problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the correct way to embed a flash movie:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>      
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="506" height="310" id="player" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="http://test.eu-seed.net/safenet/pict/banner3.1.swf" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf" width="506" height="310">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://test.eu-seed.net/safenet/pict/banner3.1.swf" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also recomend you using swfObject.